# Error while deploying smart contract (quorum-examples tutorial by truffle)

Tags: truffle-migration, quorum

:~workspace/myproject$truffle migrate --reset

## Compiling your contracts...

> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Replacing Migrations...
Migrations: 0xA501AfD7d6432718daF4458Cfae8590d88de818E
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_simplestorage.js
Deploying SimpleStorage...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 2 expected 1!
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfParams (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/~/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:32:1)
    at Object._createTxObject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:699:1)
    at Contract.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:504:1)
    at Function.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/lib/execute.js:214:1)
    at constructor.detectNetwork.then.network (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/lib/contract/constructorMethods.js:56:1)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
Truffle v5.0.12 (core: 5.0.12)
Node v8.16.0

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste the script you're using for the deployment, however from the error it looks like you're passing two parameters to the simple_storage contract constructor whereas it only expects one (the value to initialise the storage value to).

Here is a copy from my environment:

```
// Pass 42 to the contract as the first constructor parameter
deployer.deploy(simple_storage, 42, {privateFor: ["ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="]})
```

If you are passing the correct number of parameters then try deleting the contents of the 'build' directory and redeploying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem was due to use of privateFor, I got it right after upgrading to latest version of Truffle seeing your answer to another question